# ios app design for a responsive UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multithreading, nsrunloop

I am a newbie in ios app development and have a general question about the design of apps regarding the responsiveness of the user interface. Should there always be a separate thread to deal with the UI stuff ? For example I am working on a simple game, that should detect swipe gestures at all times, other than that there is some work getting done constantly, like updating the screen with moving objects and animating them (there are no blocking calls though). The app generally works well but I have noticed that occasionally it doesn't detect a swipe gesture and was wondering if the cause is that I am doing everything in the main thread.

Should I be handling the swipe gestures in the main thread and do everything else in a separate thread ? What about the animations, should each animation have its own thread as well ?
And also what about run loops, is thread better in this case or a run loop ? (I am still confused where to use runloops even after reading some material about it online)

Comment: You can update UI only in main thread. Calculation may be made in other thread, but UI update not.

Comment: To update the UI I am using periodic timers, does that mean that the timers  will also be in the main thread ? and what about swipe gesture handlers, should they be handled in a separate thread (not the main thread) ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at `NSOperationQueue` as the best combination of simplicity and functionality.  (GCD is even simpler for easy things but almost impossible to control as your requirements increase.)

A common pattern is to receive input (on the main thread), move its processing to the background along with a request to come back to the main thread for UI updates.  Here's a template of sorts for how it can be structured:

```
@interface QueueUser : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue *workQueue;
@end

@implementation QueueUser
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _workQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        _workQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
        _workQueue.name = @"ca.philmills.Test-Background";
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)handleInput {
    [self.workQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        // Do work that may take some time
        // -->

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            // Update the UI
            // -->

        }];
    }];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get responsive UI by running UI related events and background events on two separate threads. For animations don't need to use in separate thread. Although you have advantage of using threads, try to minimize the usage of threads more. Only when you are dealing with both UI and background fetching events @ time, it will be useful.